# ASP.NET error when deploying

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I published my project to my iis server and when i try and access the site I get the following error:

```
The view 'Login' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Account/Login.aspx
~/Views/Account/Login.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Login.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Login.ascx
~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml
~/Views/Account/Login.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Login.vbhtml
```

However I know that the login.cshtml is in the location that it is looking for and it works perfectly when I debug on my pc.

What could have changed or what do I need to change in order to get it to work on the iis server?

I can only think that maybe it some how has confused the `~` part of the link with an incorrect directory?

here is the stack stace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The view 'Login' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Account/Login.aspx
~/Views/Account/Login.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Login.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Login.ascx
~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml
~/Views/Account/Login.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Login.vbhtml]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) +422
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +147
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +109
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Here  are the files in my sites directoy:

[image]

```
    /
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return View("PermissionsError");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: check the server directory of views i think the views are not properly published you will have to copy paste them manually...

Comment: @Zapnologica: can you paste the code written in login Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Set `"Build Action"` of your view to `"Content"` and publish again